# Constraint value for navigation bar in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I want to add a constraint to the navigation bar I am adding via storyboard. The purpose is for the navigation bar to be fit to the border on the left and right side. The current canvas value on the screen is -16, and it shows up correctly when I run the app. However I can't figure out why -16, and when I set it to 0 there is a gap to the border.

To reproduce, create a blank single view ios project, drag a navigation bar into the story board and try to add a constraint.

xcode 6.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the tick on "Constrain to margins" will fix it.